# What constitutes a pair in the game "L'Auberge des Pirates"?

Tags: lauberge-des-pirates

In the game "L'Auberge des Pirates", holding a pair is considered dangerous for your survival during the game. It is not clear, however, what constitutes a pair: will one visible card + one card in hand be considered a pair, or will two cards in hand be a pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [rules](https://www.origames.fr/download/1549/) (via google translate):

> This player
> shows you his cards (and to
> you alone). Your charge is successful
> if he has a pair between the
> cards in his hand and those
> that he has in front of him.

And in the description of drawing a card:

> Draw 1 card without the
> show (if it makes a pair with
> cards in your hand or those
> placed in front of you, do not say anything,
> you haven't lost until
> you are not charged).

Despite the awkwardness of the translation, it seems clear enough that when challenged, you lose if there is a pair ANYWHERE among the cards you own, whether between two cards in your hand, or one from hand and one from in play.